# CakePHP get data from a table that class belongs_to

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a model in cakePHP:

```
class PagesTable extends Table
{
  public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Pagecats');

    $this->belongsToMany('Users');
}
```

and another model PagecatsTable:

```
class PagecatsTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
}
```

which its table has two coloumns `id` and `category`

How can I  get the `category` in a function in my PagesController?

Answer (score 0):

In your PagesController, do you want the pages and their associated records? If so, you could try the below mentioned code:

```
// PagesController.php

$data = $this->Pages->find()
  ->contain('Pagecats')
  ->all();

pr($data->toArray()); // Check if you're getting the desired result.
```

Comment: `Pagecats` has a 'category' coloumn. I want its value, for my current Page